# Wrong insert order at JPA/Hibernate OneToOne bidirectional relationship with the same PK

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to set up a `OneToOne` relationship between two entities that share the same PK:

```
+----------------------------------+   +----------------+-----------------+        
|              Item                |   |              Stats               |
+----------------+-----------------+   +----------------+-----------------+
| reference (PK) |  other data...  |   | reference (PK) |  other data...  |
+----------------+-----------------+   +----------------+-----------------+
|          ABCD  |      ...        |   |          ABCD  |      ...        |
|           XYZ  |      ...        |   |           XYZ  |      ...        |
+----------------+-----------------+   +----------------+-----------------+
```

where `Stats.reference` is a FK to `Item.reference`:

```
alter table Stats 
    add constraint FK_8du3dv2q88ptdvthk8gmsipsk 
    foreign key (reference) 
    references Item;
```

This structure is generated from the following annotaded classes:

```
@Entity
public class Item {
   @Id
   private String reference;

   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "item", optional = false)
   @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
   @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
   private Stats stats;

   // ...
}

@Entity
public class Stats {

   @Id
   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "reference")
   @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)   
   private Item item;  

   // ...
}
```

A new `Item` is creted as follows:

```
Item item = new Item();
item.setReference("ABC");
Stats stats = new Stats();
stats.setItem(item);
item.setStats(stats);
session.save(item);
```

My problem is when I do `session.save(item)` the INSERT statements order are wrong. 
Hibernate first tries to insert into `Stats` table instead of `Item`, resulting in a FK constraint error.

How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Answer from @boutaya is good also give your forgein key a different name.You already have that as primary key too.

Answer (score 4):

Since your class Stats owns the association, try to do :

```
stats.setItem(item);
session.save(stats)
```

Comment: I've tried it, but the problem persists. Furthermore, I think I need to save `Item` because it has other `OneToOne` relationships with the same PK (Item -> Stats) (Item ->  Stock) (Item -> x) with the same problem as described in this example. In any case, thanks for your answer.

Comment: It should work ! Try to rename the foreign key as Shahzeb said : @JoinColumn(name = "otherName")

Comment: Should work but but it doesn't. Same error occurs, I see in the logs the `insert into Stats` statement and the constraint error. Finally I've found a fix. I've changed the annotation to: `@JoinColumn(name = "reference", referencedColumnName = "reference")` and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

since you have one to one relationship between item and state and item has stats key as FK, and here you entity object should look like this

Item{

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "stat_id", nullable=false) //incase if you allow null
private stats stats
```

}

in stats entity no need to add relation annotation, since we defined in Item

while saving , you just save item entity, stats also get inserted

```
item.setStats(stats);
session.save(item);
```

in case if you want to save stats separately and items separately,

then you have define cascade type as DETACH for stats

```
 Class Item{

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "stat_id", nullable=false) //incase if you allow null
    private stats stats
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`@JoinColumn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html) annotation in `Stats` entity isn't complete, the attribute [`referencedColumnName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#referencedColumnName()) must be specified.

> public abstract java.lang.String **referencedColumnName**
>
> (Optional) The name of the column referenced by this foreign key
>   column.

```
@Entity
public class Stats {

   @Id
   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "reference", referencedColumnName = "reference")
   @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)   
   private Item item;  

   // ...
}
```